# How to call bean method from javascript function using a4j:ajax or a4j:actionListener?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I am using JSF, richfaces 4 stuff and i want to call a bean method when javascript function trigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use  [`<a4j:jsFunction>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_jsFunction.html) , which allows you to perform Ajax requests to invoke the bean method directly from JavaScript code , and the response can be returned in a JSON format to use in a client JavaScript calls.

Please note that `<a4j:jsFunction>` is required to be inside a `<h:form>` . 
For example, you define the a4j:jsFunction likes this :

```
<h:form> 
    <a4j:jsFunction name="myJsFunction"  action="#{bean.someAction}" reRender="xxxxx"/>
 </h:form>
```

A javascript function which name  called `myJsFunction()` is created and it will invoke someAction() on the bean when being called.

For example , in your javascript function  :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function yourJavaScriptFuntion() {
    ..............;
    myJsFunction();  //bean.someAction() will invoke here
    ..............;
}
```