# Open a pop up from managed bean

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I want  to open a pop up from my managed bean.
for examlpe when a transaction done or get exception I want to open a pop up and show exception or sucessful message,and I use richfaces. 
what solution do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `<h:messages>` or `<p:messages>` if you were in Primefaces, don't know much about RichFaces any more.

```
<h:messages id="messges" globalOnly="true" />
```

If calling a method with ajax don't forget to `update=":messages"`

From your BackingBean use

```
FacesContext.addMessage
```

to print a message.

**P.S.**

With PrimeFaces you could even launch JavaScript function from your bean, lets say open a modal-panel, like so:

```
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();    
requestContext.execute("showModalPanel('myPanelId');");
```

maybe there's something similar in RichFaces too, I'll have a search.

Comment: thanks for your answer I know about showing message with <h:message> but it show the message in the same page but i want to open a pop up and then the message shown in that

Comment: what kind of Popup? JS alert?

Comment: is it important what kind of pop up is using ?
really it's not important just i want to show error message or successful message

Comment: and does any body know about Request.context in rich faces ?
it seems that it has omitted or changing in version 4

Comment: well yes, it kind of is important as your question is very scarce in details. And moreover, instead of explaining clearly what you want to achieve you give us attitude. Good luck on looking for the answer on your own!

Comment: miss understood !
I mean it's not important for me to use which kind of pop up ! , i just want a pop up with default jsf or richfaces

Answer (score 0):

Your question was already answered in this page:

> [How to call bean method from javascript function using a4j:ajax or a4j:actionListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761263/how-to-call-bean-method-from-javascript-function-using-a4jajax-or-a4jactionlis)

With these components you should be able to open a pre-defined dialog or popup panel with javascript. Good luck.

Comment: thanks , but I want to do exactly the opposit thing , I want to call a javaScript function from a method in my managed bean